# using .htaccess to block tor servers

Tags: .htaccess, ip, blocking, tor

I have a large list of tor servers, maybe 2,000+ servers that I would like to ban from registering accounts on my site.  Is it viable to block the entire list I have in an .htaccess file or will this cause the server to slow down in the same way having thousands of hosts in iptables will?

Is there another alternative?  I have captcha already but bots aren't the problem.  The problem is users using tor to circumvent bans.

Comment: I think this site is not appropriate for this question.  You should move it to http://superuser.com

Comment: @Pino If anything, I think http://serverfault.com would be more appropriate as it's about server performance.

Comment: Try to limit the block to only the registration url, but for example putting the htaccess in a separate folder. I think changing the php to do this check would be preferred, but you may not be able to do that.

Comment: My solution was to create a sort of 'proxy gateway' that checks if the IP is on a list of 4000+ hourly updating tor exit/entry nodes and sets a session for them if they aren't..  Tor is the biggest issue as most web proxies don't respond to header() in PHP which means they are rendered useless anyway.